# Swift 3 How to save and load data

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm a software development student and for a school project me and a friend are making a iOS Swift game and we are learning Swift 3 as we progress in the game aspects.

Now, we have come to the part of the development where we question how is game data going to be saved (I'm talking about scores, player's name, in-game money, if the player plays in mute or unmute.. you know that kind of stuff)

The game uses an avatar and the player can customize it, so data customization needs to be saved too. 
Right now we manage this data throught variables like

```
var eyeColor = "#04ff45"
var eyetype = 3 // And so on
```

I have done some research on this and found that there are various methods we could use.
Like, we could use `Core Data` or a Dictionary or a JSON file.

I'd like to know which could be the best/easiest way to acomplish this, if we need to use any specific libraries and some basic code on how to write/read the data

Thank you very much

Comment: Asking what is "best" or "easiest", or about what library to use, is not really suitable for Stack Overflow. You need to be programming something already and have a specific issue with it. — If this is just the player vs. the computer, though, and since you are evidently beginners, I would suggest just storing the state constantly in UserDefaults. It's easy and convenient.

Comment: I agree with Matt, for something this simple Google for a NSUserDefaults tutorial in Swift 3. Once you have a good grasp of how that works, you might look into Core Data to beef up your skills in data storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to save scores is by using `NSUserDefaults`
To save settings such as volume, you can follow the model I have below.

```
//When you tap on the mute button, execute this code.


   if soundSwitch { //true

       UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "SoundSwitch")
       soundSwitch = false

    } else { //false

       UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "SoundSwitch")
       soundSwitch = true

    }
```

If you are saving players money, name and all this other stuff, it would be better to save them in some kind of database. I'm not sure if you can do that with GameCenter.

Comment: What does use of NSUserDefaults make the best way of saving game score data?

Comment: @ElTomato It's just a small value to save and an easy way of saving and manipulating.

Comment: @AdanSandoval If you want to retrieve the scores after saving, just call `let score = UserDefaults.standard.int(forKey: "Score")`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to save data you are working with on the device would be to use  `NSUserDefaults`. All you have to do is create a `key`, and store a `value` under that `key`. You can then use the `key` to access the value later and it is stored on the phone's permanent memory.

For example, you would use the user defaults to create a key called "eye color", store a value under that key, and then access it later using the term that you know the value is stored under (i.e. the key). This is a very simple way of storing such information.